# I can't add dialog in a modeless box

Tags: c#, message, messagebox, modeless

I want to create a modeless box but can't add dialog or message in the box.
Right now this is what I have, the `.Text` is shown as the title in the top bar of the box.

```
    Form popUP = new Form();
    popUP.Text = "Title";
    popUP.Show();
```

Comment: The `Text` property of `Form` sets the form's title - it does not add a label to the form.  The control that does that is `Label`  Perhaps you want `MessageBox.Show()` instead?  I suggest you look up some basic Winform tutorials as these are very basic concepts.

Comment: But that makes a modal box, not modeless.